# How to synchronize two Mysql Workbench diagrams?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm work in a development group, any can add, edit or remove tables of a MySQL Workbench ERD Diagram.

I don't know any strategy for merge / synchronize the changes in both diagrams.

Sincronize positions over the diagram on each new table, removed tables.

I have a MySQL model of 130 tables, the ERD diagram is too big, tools as GIT don't work on .mwb files.

Answer (score 4):

**[Solution]**

If you have two or more .mwb files and want to merge models into only one file, then open file1.mwb and go to 

***File -> Include Model -> Select file2.mwb*** and the model appears in the file1.mwb

Comment: when I do this, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is an hack, but do a "Database > Synchronize with Any Source" of both diagrams into the same database and in the future use just one diagram.

Comment: But, it does not sync the position of each table, I have only one diagram, but the file is shared between several developers.

Comment: The mwb is in binary format, I don't know an easy way of tracking or making a diff on it. In my case I commit it every time and it's almost always a total rewrite.

Comment: Yes, I still do not know an automated way of merging it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I notice that the mwb file is a zip of an xml file, probably there should be a way to use the xml directly

Comment: Good for @albanx who found that mwb is a zip. However, I noticed that in the zip there is not just an xml file but also an sqlite DB (no sure how important or changing it is).

Comment: @DavidLopez what a fatality I am working again with mysql workbench these days. Back in 2014 I was working on a project where we needed to sync schema change from different commits, otherwise we had to edit this file and make sure no one other was editing it.